# 'expected a character, but string of length # found' Encryption Program not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, ascii, typeerror

My code:

```
def Encryption(text):
   for I in text:
      string = ""
      ASCII = ord(text)
      Result = ASCII + Offset
      if Result > 126:
         Result -= 94
      else:
         Result = Result
      ResultASCII = chr(Result)
      string += ResultASCII
```

For my first piece of GCSE coursework, we had to make an encryption program. The final part that we have to make is the part that actually encrypts your message. I've used this code, however it comes up with an error of:

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length # found
```

How do I get it to detect a string instead of just a character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ord` argument is not string, it must be single character:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
```

you can try something like this to loop over string:

```
>>> a = 'hello'
>>> [ ord(x) for x in a ]
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

replace this :

```
ASCII = ord(text)
```

to this:

```
ASCII = ord(I)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I fit this into my code? I tried doing ASCII = ord(x) for x in a but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry if I've been unclear, this code is part of my GCSE coursework and it's basically to encrypt a message using the ASCII chart, then giving an 8-character key to the user so they can decrypt it in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
ord: (c)                                                                                                             │
│ ord(c) -> integer                                                                                                    │                                                                                                                     
│ Return the integer ordinal of a one-character string.    

>>> ord('ab')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

>>> ord('a')
97
```