# TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 5 found

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, logical-operators

I need to do a limete of type 4 characters, with numbers it goes and does not return error, but with letters it returns that error as it is in the title. I need to limit from "0 to 9" and "A to D".
In the limiteUsuario() method, everything is ok.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class loginUser:
    def __init__(self, window, master=None):   
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title("System F2T")

        #Definicoes de fonte p/ o layout de login
        self.fonteTitulo = ("Arial","10","bold")
        self.fontePadrao = ("Arial", "10")

        self.var = StringVar() #create the var first before you assign them
        self.var2 = StringVar()

        #Labels e campos de texto do sistema de login
        self.userLabel = Label(text="Digite seu usuário:", font=self.fontePadrao,bg="#000",fg="#FFF").place(x=27,y=60)
        self.user = Entry(textvariable=self.var, font=self.fontePadrao,bg="#FFF",fg="#000")
        self.user.place(x=140,y=60,width=110)

        self.senhaLabel = Label(text="Digite sua senha:", font=self.fontePadrao,bg="#000",fg="#FFF").place(x=29,y=90)
        self.senha = Entry(textvariable=self.var2, font=self.fontePadrao,bg="#FFF",fg="#000")
        self.senha.place(x=140,y=90,width=110)

        self.max_user = 1
        self.var.trace("w", self.limiteUsuario)
        self.max_senha = 4
        self.var2.trace("w", self.limiteSenha)

    def limiteUsuario(self,*args):
        u = self.var.get()
        if len(u) == 1 and not 65<=ord(u)<=68 and not 48<=ord(u)<=57: # you can also use *if not u in "ABCD"*
            self.var.set("")
        elif len(u) > 1:
            if not 65<=ord(u[-1])<=68: # retirar ultimo caracter caso nao seja digito
                self.var.set(u[:-1])
            else: # aproveitar apenas os primeiros 5 chars
                self.var.set(u[:self.max_user])

    def limiteSenha(self,*args):
        text = self.var2.get()
        text = ''.join(char for char in text if char in 'ABCD')
        if len(text) == 4 and not 65<=ord(text)<=68 and not 48<=ord(text)<=57: # you can also use *if not u in "ABCD"*
            self.var2.set("")
        elif len(text) > 4:
            if not 65<=ord(text[-1])<=68: # retirar ultimo caracter caso nao seja digito
                self.var2.set(text[:-1])
            else: # aproveitar apenas os primeiros 5 chars
                self.var2.set(text[:self.max_senha])
        print(self.var2.set(text))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root['bg'] = "#000"
    loginUser(root)
    #Tamanho da janela
    root.geometry("330x200")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This ['expected a character, but string of length # found' Encryption Program not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27126444/6194097) question might help.

Comment: @KushanGunasekera But it's not encryption, it's just limiting, for user I got it, I need to password, but it's not giving.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with your code. Tried input numbers and letters but first input field only seems to accept one character, second field accepts any four characters...

Comment: `ord()` can convert only single char - `ord("a")`, not `ord("hello")`. If you have string with many chars then you can use `for`-loop to work with single chars. `for char in "hello": ord(char)`

Answer (score 0):

`ord()` can convert only single char - like `ord("a")` - but you have string with many chars - like `ord("BXA7D")`

You can use `for` loop to work with every char separatelly

```
text = "BXA7D"  # text = self.var2.get()
text = ''.join(char for char in text if char in 'ABCD')
print(text)  # self.var2.set(text)

# BAD
```

or longer

```
text = "BXA7D"  # text = self.var2.get()
result = []

for char in text:
    if char in 'ABCD':
        result.append(char)

text = ''.join(result)
print(text)  # self.var2.set(text)

# BAD
```

---

**EDIT:** I don't know what result exactly you want. Delete all string if there is `ABCD0123456789` or remove only chars `ABCD0123456789`

This remove all string if there is char `ABCD0123456789` or cut to 5 chars.

```
def limiteSenha(self,*args):
    s = self.var2.get()
    if len(s) > 5:
        for char in s:
            if char not in 'ABCD0123456789':
                s = ""
                break # exit for-loop because there is no need to check rest
        self.var2.set(s[:self.max_senha])
    elif len(s) == 5:
        if not 65<=ord(s[-1])<=68: # retirar ultimo caracter caso nao seja digito
            self.var2.set(s[:-1])
        else: # aproveitar apenas os primeiros 5 chars
            self.var2.set(s[:self.max_senha])
```

Comment: Okay, so in case I would put it below the self.var2.set ()?

Comment: In case I did not understand where this line of code fits, sorry I'm a little new at it.

Comment: see comments in code - between `self.var2.get()` and `self.var2.set()`

Comment: It would be like this? I put it in the initial code. So he still continues to enter characters other than "ABCD". Sorry for my foolishness

Comment: see comments in example - you have to use `text = self.var2.get()` - there is no sense to use `text = "BXA7D"` . This `text = "BXA7D"` is in code only to run example without rest of code - this way everyone can test how it works.

Comment: see new example in answer

Comment: With that, he's typing everyone. I did a little different from yours, but the password limit it is not catching, I am able to type without limit.

Comment: I updated in my code, there just type "ABCD", in case it is ok! But now it's without the password limit I did not understand.